# about angularjs deferred resolve position

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a data should be make consistency. But I have a each loop. I'm not sure I put `resolve` and `reject` position is right. This is my sample code.

```
function getCount(content) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
      query,
      [data],
      function(tx, res) {
        var count = res.rows.item(0).cnt;

        if (count === 0) {
          var commit = content.commit;

          commit.forEach(function(entry) {
            tx.executeSql(
              query,
              [data],
              function(tx, res){
                deferred.resolve(res); // here is right?
              },
              function (e) {
                deferred.reject(e); // here is right?
              }
            );
          });
        }
        else{
          deferred.resolve(res);
        }
      },
      function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

And I think `resolve` and `reject` should be call once, not on the each loop, so I modify to this version, is this right? Thanks your help.

```
function getCount(content) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
      query,
      [data],
      function(tx, res) {
        var count = res.rows.item(0).cnt;

        if (count === 0) {
          var commit = content.commit;
          var status = true;
          commit.forEach(function(entry) {
            tx.executeSql(
              query,
              [data],
              function(tx, res){},
              function (e) {
                status = false;
              }
            );
          });

          // here is right?
          if (status) {
            deferred.resolve(res);
          }
          else {
            deferred.reject();
          }
        }
        else{
          deferred.resolve(res);
        }
      },
      function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

**---------- Edit -------------**

Check in the each loop

```
function getCount(content) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
      query,
      [data],
      function(tx, res) {
        var count = res.rows.item(0).cnt;

        if (count === 0) {
          var commit = content.commit;
          var commit_index = 0;

          commit.forEach(function(entry, index) {
            tx.executeSql(
              query,
              [data],
              function(tx, res){
                commit_index++;
              },
              function (e) {}
            );

            if (index === (commit.length - 1)) {
              if (commit_index === commit.length) {
                deferred.resolve(res);
              }
              else {
                deferred.reject(res);
              }
            }

          });
        }
        else{
          deferred.resolve(res);
        }
      },
      function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes resolve and reject should be call once, and forEach loop is aync form of loop. So you can't check

```
 ` if (status) {
   deferred.resolve(res);
   }
   else {
    deferred.reject();
   }`
```

So you have to resolve or reject in each loop but when the last iteration come. you can check last iteration in each loop when length of commit is equal of indexOf entry.

Comment: Hi, according your answer I modify code on the question, Does it your mean?

Comment: Yes but you have to check length in 
'function(tx, res){
                commit_index++;
// here to put your length check

              }'